# Columns parameter doesn't work when exporting excel file (pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, parameters

```
url = 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/25th-nujf/rows.csv'
baby_names = pd.read_csv(url)

girls = baby_names[baby_names['Gender'] == 'FEMALE']
boys = baby_names[baby_names['Gender'] == 'MALE']

excel_file = pd.ExcelWriter('Baby_Names.xlsx')

girls.to_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Girls', index=False)
boys.to_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Boys', index=False, columns=['Year of Birth', 'Gender', 'Ethnicity'])

excel_file.save()
```

The first sheet contains and should contain all the original columns, while the second only the ones I mentioned. However, this last one still contains all the original columns, still displaying the three additional ones, as if I had never entered the `columns=` parameter.

UPDATE: this format doesn't work either:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('Baby_Names.xlsx') as excel_file:
    girls.to_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Girls', index=False)
    boys.to_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Boys', index=False, columns=['Year of Birth', 'Gender', 'Ethnicity'])
    excel_file.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

[The Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) provides an example of writing multiple sheets using the ExcelWriter as follows:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```

maybe try to write both sheets using this single file context?

```
 excel_file = pd.ExcelWriter('Baby_Names.xlsx')
 with excel_file as writer:  
    girls.to_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Girls', index=False)
    boys.to_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Boys', index=False, columns=['Year of Birth', 'Gender', 'Ethnicity'])
```